# How to install Ruby 3.0.4 on macOS Monterey with rbenv

Tags: ruby, homebrew, rbenv, macos-monterey

I'm trying to install Ruby for programming on my macOS Monterey with Apple M1 chip.

I started off by following these steps:

1. `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

Ok, great! That works...

2. `brew install rbenv`

This also worked. I double checked and got: `rbenv 1.2.0 is already installed and up-to-date.`

3. `rbenv init`

This outputs this: `eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"` so I change it to that, close terminal, and relaunch it.

4. `rbenv install 3.0.4`

And this gets this:

```
ME@0107 ~ % rbenv install 3.0.4                                   
Downloading openssl-1.1.1q.tar.gz...
-> https://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/d7939ce614029cdff0b6c20f0e2e5703158a489a72b2507b8bd51bf8c8fd10ca
Installing openssl-1.1.1q...
patching file test/v3ext.c
Installed openssl-1.1.1q to /Users/ME/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4

Downloading ruby-3.0.4.tar.gz...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/3.0/ruby-3.0.4.tar.gz
Installing ruby-3.0.4...
ruby-build: using readline from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (macOS 12.5 using ruby-build 20220726)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/bn/gcvl_htn4lz2y2d9h215n0vc0000gn/T/ruby-build.20220814230938.91093.ruEkdU
Results logged to /var/folders/bn/gcvl_htn4lz2y2d9h215n0vc0000gn/T/ruby-build.20220814230938.91093.log

Last 10 log lines:
The Ruby yaml extension was not compiled.
ERROR: Ruby install aborted due to missing extensions
Configure options used:
  --prefix=/Users/ME/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4
  --with-openssl-dir=/Users/ME/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/openssl
  --enable-shared
  --with-readline-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/readline
  CC=clang
  LDFLAGS=-L/Users/ME/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib 
  CPPFLAGS=-I/Users/ME/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/include 
ME@0107 ~ %
```

Here's where it gets crazy:

I type in: `rbenv global 3.1.2`
No output... If I typed anything else, terminal would say:

```
rbenv: version `3.0.2' not installed
```

but then I type... `ruby -v`
And I get...

```
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin18]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might be missing `libyaml`, which is needed for compiling the `yaml` gem. Try `brew install libyaml`, and then try to compile Ruby again with rbenv.

Comment: Check https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/wiki#macos  and what does the log say?

Answer (score 0):

You can run `arch -arm64 rbenv install 3.0.4` and it should install without issues on M1 Chips Devices.